# python clear csv file

Tags: python, csv

how can I clear a complete csv file with python. Most forum entries that cover the issue of deleting row/columns basically say, write the stuff you want to keep into a new file. I need to completely clear a file - how can I do that?

Comment: What does "clearing" a file even mean? You can just delete it, or replace it with a 0-byte file.

Comment: Do you want to keep the column headers but delete the data?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Basically you want to truncate the file, this can be any file. In this case it's a csv file so:

```
filename = "filewithcontents.csv"
# opening the file with w+ mode truncates the file
f = open(filename, "w+")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 16):

Your question is rather strange, but I'll interpret it literally.  Clearing a file is not the same as deleting it.

You want to open a `file` object to the CSV file, and then `truncate` the file, bringing it to zero length.

```
f = open("filename.csv", "w")
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

If you want to delete it instead, that's just a os filesystem call:

```
import os
os.remove("filename.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python csv module is only for reading and writing whole CSV files but not for manipulating them. If you need to filter data from file then you have to read it, create a new csv file and write the filtered rows back to new file.